# undefined en select - usando each en ajax

Tags: laravel, ajax, html-select

necesito ayuda para saber cual es mi fallo. trato de hacer un select en donde sus opciones se llenen con los registros de una tabla, para ello estoy usando ajax. pero al ejecutarse, en la lista se muestra el siguiente mensaje en el select. y no estoy seguro cual sea la causa ya que no marca ningun error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Crei que era porque ajax no me esta trayendo los datos, pero en consola si me los muestra.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

HTML

```
<select class="form-control" name="estado" id="historial"></select>
```

JS

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url_his, 
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data,function(key, registro) {
                    console.log(registro); //imprime lo de la imagen 2.
                    $("#historial").append('<option value='+registro.id+'>'+registro.id+'</option>');                                          
                });       
            },
            error: function(data) {
              alert('error');
            }
          });
```

Controlador

```
public function historial(Request $request)
{  
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        $data = logevento::select('id', 'created_at')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();  
        return response()->json(['data' => $data]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Lo de la imagen 2 es un array de objetos. Supongo que tendrías que hacer el each sobre `data.data`, ya que desde el controlador devuelves un objeto con un atributo `data` dentro del cual se encuentra el array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código debería ser algo así en success te envía la información completa de la respuesta la reemplace por "res" para que puedas obtener los datos con res.data

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://url.api',
  success: function(res) {

    const hitorial = $("#historial"); // Por fuera de la iteración para que no se cree constantemente
    $.each(res.data, function(key, registro) {
      hitorial.append('<option value='+registro['id']+'>'+registro['id']+'</option>'
      );    
    });
  },
  error: function() {
    alert("No se ha podido obtener la información");
  }
});
```

Comment: Gracias, no sabia como aplicarlo!

Answer (score 1):

Prueba colocando: registro['id'].

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url_his, 
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data,function(key, registro) {
                console.log(registro); //imprime lo de la imagen 2.
                $("#historial").append('<option value='+registro['id']+'>'+registro['id']+'</option>');                                          
            });       
        },
        error: function(data) {
          alert('error');
        }
      });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder! <3